# Which is faster xsl:function or xsl:call-template

Tags: xslt, comparison, xslt-2.0

I have to process large data and confuse between use of `xsl:function` or `xsl:call-template`. Just want to know which is faster and appropriate to use.

```
<xsl:variable name="tabledata">
    <xsl:copy-of select="table:table_process(.)"/>            
</xsl:variable>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="tabledata">
    <xsl:call-template name="table_process">
        <xsl:with-param name="table_data" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Go ahead, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would have to measure performance with a particular XSLT processor and a particular set of XML input and XSLT code. I would prefer to use `<xsl:variable name="tabledata" select="table:table_process(.)"/>` as the most compact and elegant XSLT 2 notation, it might also perform better or at least consume less memory as that way you don't need to copy the result of the function call but directly use it. It all depends on what the function does exactly and whether you need to copy its result or not.